# Pandas: apply stats.ttest_1samp on every row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I have a dataframe zdf that looks like the following:

```
   Index       A    B    C    Mean
2008-11-21    23   12   16    18
2008-11-24    26   14   15    17
2008-11-25    28   20   21    25
2008-11-26    25   26   27    26
```

I am trying to apply a two-sided t-test on each row,and storing the result in a new column. Using  `stats.ttest_1samp`

```
from scipy.stats import stats
```

It takes a first parameter a list (all values on each row except last), and a second parameter, the mean (last column in zdf). It will return two values: The t-statistic and the p-value. I am trying the following:

```
for i in range(zdf.shape[0]+1):
    zdf.ix[i,'ttest'] = stats.ttest_1samp(list(zdf.iloc[i,:-1]),zdf.iloc[i,-1])
```

I keep getting a value error for some reason, but surely there's a better way to apply this without for looping?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you show us the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't set an array element with a sequence with `.ix[]` so you need to pass a single array such has:

```
for i in range(zdf.shape[0]+1):
    zdf.ix[i,'ttest_res1'] = stats.ttest_1samp(zdf.iloc[i,:-1].values,zdf.iloc[i,-1])[1]
    zdf.ix[i,'ttest_res2'] = stats.ttest_1samp(zdf.iloc[i,:-1].values,zdf.iloc[i,-1])[2]
```

also, I would pass an array instead of a list in the first argument with `.values`